# Go to next offset position kakfa

Tags: apache-kafka

How can I go to the next offset position ignoring the current position.  Currently Im using ‘seektoend()’ but want to use something that goes to the next offset rather than the end.

Comment: using seek(). --> seek(partition, currentOffset+1)

Comment: Is current offset position retrieved by position()?

Comment: The current position will be given by the ConsumerRecord, thanks to its offset() method. https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html#offset()

Comment: But if I don’t have the ConsumerRecord available?

Comment: consume one message in order to get the offset then.

Comment: The whole issue is when I try to consume a message and if there is a key mismatch, it gives an exception and gets stuck at an offset. So, I can't fully read the message. So I have a flag that tries to move the offset when I restart the server. At this point there is no message. Is there any other way to take it to the next offset.

Comment: I thought kafkaConsumer.position()  + 1should suffice

Comment: If you seek to the end, there is no next offset... And not clear what you mean by "key mismatch"... If you get an exception, then sounds like a deserialization or other consumer config issue